# Django заполнить кастомную форму данными после ошибки в валидации

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Есть форма, для нее прописаны условия валидации.

```
class createCommForm(forms.Form):
    desc = forms.CharField()
    from_rack = forms.CharField()
    from_equip = forms.CharField()
    from_port = forms.CharField()
    
    def clean_desc(self, *args, **kwargs):
        desc = self.cleaned_data.get('desc')
        if len(desc) < 3:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Короткое описание')
        return desc

    def  clean_from_port(self, *args, **kwargs):
        portId = self.cleaned_data.get('from_port')
        port = Port.objects.get(id=portId)
        if port.desc == 'Free':
            raise forms.ValidationError('Порт свободен!')
        return portId
```

Если форма не проходит валидацию, страница перезагружается и данные с формы пропадают, появляются нужные ошибки валидации. Необходимо заполнить поля, так же как они были до валидации. Понял как вернуть обычные текстовые поля.

```
<div class="form-edit_field">
            <label for="id_desc" class="label-edit">Описание</label>
            <input type="text" name="desc" class="input-edit" placeholder="Введите описание..." {% if form.is_bound %} value="{{ form.desc.value }}"{% endif %}> 
</div>
```

Так же у меня есть 3 select в кастомной форме. Они у меня заполняются через AJAX запросы и изначально они пусты, кроме первого, которое заполняется при загрузке страницы. Остальные заполняются только при изменении значения предыдущего поля. Как в них можно поместить выбранные до валидации формы значения?

views.py

```
def createComm(request):
    form = createCommForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('addComm'):
            form = createCommForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                Commutation.objects.create(desc=request.POST.get('desc'), dest_from='-')
                return redirect('/office/commutation/')
    return render(request, 'edit/create_comm.html', {'form': form})
```

HTML:

```
<form action="#" method="POST" class="form-edit">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-edit_field">
            <label for="id_desc" class="label-edit">Описание</label>
            <input type="text" name="desc" class="input-edit" placeholder="Введите описание..." {% if form.is_bound %} value="{{ form.desc.value }}"{% endif %}> 
        </div>
        {{ form.desc.errors }}
        <div class="form-edit_field">
            <label for="from_rack" class="label-edit">Откуда</label>
            <select name="from_rack" id="inputFromRack" class="input-edit">
                <option value="empty" selected>Выберите шкаф...</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-edit_field" style="align-self: flex-end;">
            <select name="from_equip" id="inputFromEquip" class="input-edit">
                <option value="empty" selected>Выберите оборудование...</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        {{ form.from_port.errors }}
        <div class="form-edit_field" style="align-self: flex-end;">
            <select name="from_port" id="inputFromPort" class="input-edit">
                <option value="empty" selected>Выберите порт...</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <button class="btn-main" type="submit" value="addComm" name="addComm">Добавить</button>
    </form>
```

JS:

```
let inputFromRack = document.getElementById('inputFromRack')
let inputFromEquip = document.getElementById('inputFromEquip')
let inputFromPort = document.getElementById('inputFromPort')

window.onload = function(){
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/create-comm-rack/', {
                method:'GET'
            })
            .then(data => data.json())
            .then(function(data){
                for (var i in data){
                    var options = `
                        <option value="${data[i].id}">ТШ ${data[i].name}</option>
                    `
                    inputFromRack.innerHTML += options
                }
                // console.log(data)
    })
}

inputFromRack.onchange = function(){
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/create-comm-equip/', {
                method:'POST',
                headers:{
                    'Content-type':'application/json',
                    'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,
                },
                body:inputFromRack.value
            })
            .then(data => data.json())
            .then(function(data){
                inputFromEquip.innerHTML = '<option value="" selected="">Выберите оборудование...</option>';
                for (var i in data){
                    var options = `
                        <option value="${data[i].id}">${data[i].place} ${data[i].name}</option>
                    `
                    inputFromEquip.innerHTML += options
                }
                // console.log(data)
    })
}

inputFromEquip.onchange = function(){
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/create-comm-port/', {
            method:'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-type':'application/json',
                'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,
            },
            body:inputFromEquip.value
        })
        .then(data => data.json())
        .then(function(data){
            inputFromPort.innerHTML = '<option value="" selected="">Выберите порт...</option>';
            for (var i in data){
                var options = `
                    <option value="${data[i].id}">Порт ${data[i].num}</option>
                `
                inputFromPort.innerHTML += options
            }
            //console.log(data)
            
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. вариант
   Не перезгружай страницу. Если уж ты с помощью ajax формируешь данные, то и отправляй форму тоже с помощью ajax. и возвращай информацию об ошибках, если форма не валидна, и ссылку для редиректа если форма валидна. и по ответу либо показывай информацию об ошибках, либо редирект на другую страницу
2. вариант при формировании формы в `__init__`
   для тех полей, в которые данные формируются через ajax добавляй `.choices` на основе данных, введенных пользователем. Как-то так:

```
class TestForm(forms.Form):
    text_field = forms.CharField(label='field1')
    select_field = forms.ChoiceField(label='choices', choices=())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.data.get('text_field'):
            self.fields['select_field'].choices = [(self.data.get('text_field'), self.data.get('text_field'))]
```

тут я устанавливаю значения в select в зависимости от введенного в первом поле. А ты реализуй ту логику, которую тебе надо.